# Do 16 hole chromatic harmonicas exist in the key of F?

Tags: harmonica, chromatic

Some songs are in the key of F so trying to fill in or accompany the singer on a key of C harmonica is nearly impossible.
I have a chromatic harmonica in the key of F but it"s only a 12 hole so doesn't go high enough on the notes.

Comment: Having a 48 chromonica even in C means the button will generally speaking only be utilised to change B into Bb (or A into Bb), so it would do a fairly good job. A good question! +1

Comment: I think you should be able to cover 4 octaves with a 16 hole harmonica. And since it is chromatic you can play in any key. Some keys will be easier than others, but F, with just one flat, shouldn't be too hard. Use the slide to get the accidental in there.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing:

- Suzuki offers it's 12 hole chromatic harmonicas in various keys
  (including F), but not it's 14 or 16 holes. See:
  https://www.suzukimusic.co.uk/products/harmonica/chromatics.html
- The same is true of Seydel, only some of it's 12 hole chromatics come in
  other keys than C: https://www.seydel1847.de/chromatics.
- The same is true of Hohner, only some of it's 12 hole chromatics come in other keys than C: https://www.hohner.de/en/instruments/harmonicas/chromatic
- As far as I can tell,the same is true of Eastop.

However some of those companies will allow you to order custom-made harmonicas (at a much higher cost, obviously). I know at least Seydel and Hohner do this, so possibly you could ask them for a 16 hole chromatic in F.

Having said that, it's worth noting that the vast majority of Chromatic players just use a harmonica in C (one exception being Irish music players, who tend to use chromatics in D or G).

Playing in the key of F on a Chromatic in C is fairly trivial - you only need to use the slider when playing the Bb (which you will find on holes -2, 3, 7 and 11 draw with the slider in).